# B plus tree deletion JAVA

Tags: java, tree

I found this code on github https://github.com/shandysulen/B-Plus-Tree/blob/master/bplustree.java

I implemented a new function to find the smallest element of the b plus tree.

```
public int searchMin() {

        if (isEmpty()) {
          return 0;
        }

        LeafNode ln =  this.firstLeaf ;
        DictionaryPair dps = ln.dictionary[0];
        double index = dps.key;

        return index;
      }
```

All is working fine. But when I delete the smallest element of the b plus tree
and then run this function to find the next smallest element error appears. I think the delete function has an error but I can't figure out what it is.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "key" because "dps" is null
```

Comment: When I increase the order of the tree the problem appears to be fixed still don't know why but it works.

Comment: All information needed to understand this question should be embedded in the question, not behind a link. As a first reaction, I'd say you need to contact the author of that github project.